# Please help me understand this piece of scala with patterns in

Tags: scala

```
val withDefault: Option[Int] => Int = {
    case Some(x) => x
    case None => 0
}
```

What I don't understand about it is, how is this a legal function literal? Specifically, what is that 'Int' doing after the => ?

I thought that function literals were like:

```
(x: Int) => x * x
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Option[Int] => Int` is the type

Comment: This is very seldomly-used syntax; ordinarily one would simply write `def withDefault(o: Option[Int]): Int = o match { ... }`.

Comment: Of course, in the case of this specific example, it'd be even better to write it `val withDefaults: Option[Int] => Int = _ getOrElse 0`...

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo `val withDefault = (_: Option[Int]) getOrElse 0`. Now there's no `Int` after the arrow to confuse anybody.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to define an anonymous function. From the language reference section 8.5 (http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf):

```
An anonymous function can be deﬁned by a sequence of cases
  { case p1 => b1 ... case pn => bn }
```

I believe your example is exactly the same as:

```
  val withDefault: Option[Int] => Int = x => x match {
    case Some(x) => x
    case None => 0
  }
```